# parameter optimization of black-box function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I need an elegant, simple system to find out what is the highest value returned from a deterministic function given one, or more, parameters.

I know that there is a nice implementation of genetic algorithms in MATLAB, but actually, in my case this is an overkill. I need something simpler.

Any idea?

Comment: This highly depends on your function. Do you have a derivative available? Is the function convex? Are there constraints involved? Are you looking for a global/local maximum? What accuracy is sufficient? This is a complete research topic in mathematics. See for instance http://www.mathworks.nl/help/optim/ug/choosing-a-solver.html

Comment: The function is assumed to be imperscrutable, as I already stated in the question: black box. The only way to get a hint on its behavior is to query the function with a parameter and a value to be maximized is returned. This way it's impossible to determine if a maximum/minimum is global or local, so a local maximum/minimum may be good enough. I know that this is a complete research topic, for this reason I wrote on stackoverflow instead of math.stackexchange, just to get to know if there are any existing handy implementations in MATLAB.

Comment: `fminbnd` or `fminsearch` are the best places to start, this is an incredibly broad question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot find a maximum with Matlab directly, but you can minimize something. Multiplying your function by -1 transformes your "find the maximum"-problem into a "find the minimum"-problem, which can be found with `fminsearch`

```
f = @(x) 2*x - 3*x.^2; % a simple function to find the maximum from
minusf = @(x) -1*f(x); % minus f, find minimum from this function
x = linspace(-2,2,100);
plot(x, f(x));
xmax = fminsearch(minusf, -1);
hold on
plot(xmax,f(xmax),'ro') % plot the minimum of minusf (maximum of f)
```

The result looks like this: [image: this]

Answer (score 1):

A real simple idea is to use a grid search approach, maybe with mesh refinements. A better idea would be to use a more advanced derivative-free optimizer, such as the Nelder-Mead algorithm. This is available in [`fminsearch`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html).

You could also try algorithms from the global optimization toolbox: for example [`patternsearch`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/gads/patternsearch.html) or the infamous [`simulannealbnd`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/gads/simulannealbnd.html).